# Excel - if a range of cells equals a value from a list I want to populate the value of another cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a formula that will return the value of one cell if a range of cells equal a value specific in a list.

For example:

```
    A1 = Orange
    B1:B5 = My Data 
    If B1:B5 = Red, Blue, or Green, display the value from A1
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim a as Range, listValues() as string 'array of string
Dim str as string, i as integer


str = "Red;Blue;Green"
listValues = Split(str,";") 'split str using ";"
for i= Lbound(listValues) to Ubound(listValues) 'loop thru the array
    Set a = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Find(what:=listValues(i), lookat:=xlWhole) 
    if Not a Is Nothing Then
        'value found
        a.value = Range("A1").value
    end if
next i
```

I've adapted @Davesexcel 's resolution, check his one:
[How to avoid using select in VBA for variable cell ranges?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38833596/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-vba-for-variable-cell-ranges/38834014#38834014)

This resolution from RonDeBruin is nice too:

http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win006.htm

Answer (score 0):

Put your values some where in a column:

[image]

Then a simple formula in C1:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(B1,E:E,0)),$A$1,"")
```

If a match is found it will return its row number.  The If tests if it is a number or an error.  If it is a number, a match is found and the value in A1 is returned.  Otherwise it returns an empty string.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: I got it to work on a single cell however I need to have it verify on a range. When I use the below formula it doesn't display the value from A9 even though the logic test returns true. Any suggestions? =IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(F9:U9,W43:W50,0)),$A$9,"")

Comment: You will need to enter that formula with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when leaving Edit mode.  If done properly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula. @B.Witt